# "Open with GitKraken" shell extension doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, git, shell-extensions

I installed GitKraken yesterday and it works fine. I also noticed that when I rightclick a folder in Windows Explorer, I have an "Open with GitKraken" option. But when I click that, I get a messagebox saying:

> This file doesn't have a program associated with it for performing this action. [etc]

How do I fix this?

**Edit:** I don't see how this is too broad...

Answer (score 4):

Open the Windows registry editor and go to key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\GitKraken\command`.

The default value will be set to something like:
`"X:\Users\username\AppData\Local\gitkraken\update.exe" --processStart=gitkraken.exe --process-start-args="-p %L"`

Switch the last parameter from `%L` to `%V`, i.e., the command should be:
`"X:\Users\username\AppData\Local\gitkraken\update.exe" --processStart=gitkraken.exe --process-start-args="-p %V"`

Comment: This didn't work for me at first, I had to change `%V` to `\"%V\"`. Probably because the path of the project folder has spaces in them.